# Java Regex - Not an empty string, only numbers, 8 chars long

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to construct a regex that basically allows only numbers, 8 characters long and cannot be empty ie "" or have 8 blank spaces

I've been able to get two separate regex that will nearly do what I'm after: 
**^(?!\s*$).+** which does not allow empty strings, but permits white space.  Also: **^[0-9]+$** which lets me only search for numbers.

I would like to combine these regex expression and also and in a clause to match strings that are 8 characters long.

Any advice on how I could combine what I have so far?

Comment: The requirement is not clear. Does 8 characters include the spaces? What are these 8 characters? Numbers? Do you allow the number to be broken up by spaces e.g. `1234 5678`? What is up with "only number" requirement in the title?

Comment: OK, wait... 8 chars is the _total length_ or the length after surrounding spaces are removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just place `^(?!\s*$)` at start of your regex. Try this way `^(?!\s*$)[0-9\s]{8}$`?

- `^(?!\s*$)` as you know will check if entire string is not only white spaces
- `[0-9\s]` will match any digit and white space
- `{8}` means exactly 8 occurrences of element before it (in our case digit or white space)

Comment: So how come if I do something like ^(?!\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\s]$ to match alphanumerics and 0-9, no max length, it only matches a 1 character string?  If I try to match an alphanumeric string > 1 in size, I get no results?

Comment: @deanmau5 in `^(?!\s*$)[A-Za-z0-9\s]$` `(?!\s*$)` is zero with (after testing condition in (?!...) cursor will go back to its positon before that test) and `[A-Za-z0-9\s]` represent only one character that is aether in range `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9` or white space. so zero-with + one character gives you regex that will match only one character strings.

Answer (score 2):

Can't really get how the string can be 8 characters long and contain only digits and be whitespace, but for matching just 8 digits try this one:

```
^\d{8}$
```

Comment: me neither, +1 for simple answer

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a quantifier that ensures that your pattern will match a certain number of digits like so: `^[0-9]{8}$`.

**Edit:** Hm, I misread the part about white space before. Is it alright for there to be white space within the string to be matched, or just around it? If the former, I'll have to re-work my answer. If the latter, drop the `^` and `$`.

**Edit v2:** Pshemo has the day.

Comment: With or without `^` and `$`, if the regex is used with `String.matches()` or `Matcher.matches()`, the result will be the same.

Comment: its alright to have whitespace within the string (342 5843) and around ( 483928 ), just as long as the whole string isnt blank. like the following "" or "   "

Comment: @deanmau5: Please edit your question to include accept and reject test cases.

Comment: @deanmau5 see my solution; in fact, checking for the string's length first is waaay easier

Comment: @fge tied to using annotation validation, so @Pattern(regexp="blah")

Comment: @deanmau5 Ah, now I understand. Pshemo's answer should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

> ^[\d|\s]{8}$

or in java ...

```
String re = "^[\\d|\\s]{8}$";
```

Comment: You will also allow `|`...

Comment: this is close, I've updated my question to show that unfortunately I can't have 8 blank spaces :(

Answer (score 0):

First do a length check on the string to see if it's eigth chars long ;)

Then trim (to remove spaces at the beginning and end) and match with `\d+(\s+\d+)*`:

```
// No need to anchor the regex since we use .matches()
return input.length() == 8 && input.trim().matches("\\d+(\\s+\\d+)*");
```

Comment: I am afraid that input can have space at start.

Comment: @Pshemo not what the op says in a comment above

Comment: `its alright to have whitespace within the string (342 5843) and around ( 483928 )` OP comment under Derek Peterson answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh arshajil's answer will match strings with only spaces though

Comment: @Pshemo yes, and? That's what I say...

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see `trim()` in your answer. My bad.